# Codeigniter Wrong MD5

Tags: codeigniter, md5

I used Codeigniter in my project. And a form submit some datas to a controller.

in the controller;

```
echo $this->input->post('message') ---output---> hello

echo md5($this->input->post('message')) ---output---> 5d41402abc4b2a76b9719d911017c592
```

but the md5 of the "hello" is not 5d41402abc4b2a76b9719d911017c592.

Why is this happening and how i solve this problem ?

Comment: `md5('hello')` is `5D41402ABC4B2A76B9719D911017C592`

Comment: The hash is correct. Weren't you accidentally comparing the hash of `'message'` to the hash of `'hello'`?

Answer (score 1):

The output is corrrect, Here is a sample `Code`:

```
echo "hello<br>";
echo "md5 :".md5("hello");
```

Output:

```
hello
md5 :5d41402abc4b2a76b9719d911017c592
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [**do_hash**](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/security_helper.html) Permits you to create SHA1 or MD5 one way hashes suitable for encrypting passwords. Will create SHA1 by default. Examples:

```
$str=$this->input->post('message') 
$str = do_hash($str); // SHA1

$str = do_hash($str, 'md5'); // MD5
```

Comment: never use MD5 or SHA1 to encrypt password. It is unsafe to do so. Try `mcrypt` functions: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php

Comment: I was wrong, md5("hello") is 5d41402abc4b2a76b9719d911017c592. But thanks for your advice. I will use this.

Comment: @YasinOzel kewl!! check it out and if it works please accept the answer

Answer (score 1):

CodeIgniter MD5 is correct. Maybe you are looking for something else.

You can prove it [here](http://www.adamek.biz/md5-generator.php)